# s3cmd, set low verbosity

Tags: python, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I currently use s3cmd to sync backups from our servers to amazon s3. I do this using a cron similar to the following:

```
MAILTO=my@email.address
01 03 * * * s3cmd sync /root/backup/backups/ s3://somebucket/
```

This is just a sample, the files to be synced are already in the backups directory. Currently when I use this, I quite often get warnings about the upload fails (connect reset by peer) and then the retries. After 1 or 2 retries the upload generally gets there.

What I'd like to know is can I change the verbosity of s3cmd to only log output when it actually errors, rather than warns so that I only get emailed when I need to look at something?

It appears you might be able to set this in the .s3cmd preference file, but I wanted to make sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you have a newer version of `s3cmd`, try the `--quiet` (or `-q`) option:

```
MAILTO=my@email.address
01 03 * * * s3cmd sync --quiet /root/backup/backups/ s3://somebucket/
```

If not, just redirect `STDOUT` to `/dev/null` like so:

```
MAILTO=my@email.address
01 03 * * * s3cmd sync /root/backup/backups/ s3://somebucket/ >/dev/null
```

Errors are sent to `STDERR` so they will still be emailed out.

**UPDATE ABOUT S3CMD and STDERR:**

As Valguss pointed out, it seems that s3cmd always logs debug, info, warning and error messages to `STDERR` so the above methods will not work.

However, the verbosity level can be controlled from the `.s3cfg` file (located in the home directory for the user associated with the cron job in this case):

```
[default]
verbosity = ERROR
```

A verbosity level of `ERROR` can not be configured via command line parameters at this time.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've had a look, and the quiet option is in the 1.5 alpha 3 release on github, the release version on their YUM repo is 1.0. I'll give the redirection a go and see what happens.

Comment: OK, just checked and redirection dosen't work either. It appears that the warnings are sent to stderr as well. I'll email the author and see if they can shed some light.

Comment: Still get all the same output after changing `verbosity = ERROR`. Not sure why this trick doesn't work.